# Modified PyTorch loss function BCEWithLogitsLoss returns NaNs

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm trying to solve a binary classification problem (`target=0` and `target=1`) with an exception:
Some of my labels are classified as `target=0.5` on purpose, and I wish to have *zero loss* for either classifying it as 0 or 1 (i.e both classes are "correct").

I tried to implement a custom loss from scratch, based on PyTorch's [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html):

```
class myLoss(torch.nn.Module):

def __init__(self, pos_weight=1):
    super().__init__()
    self.pos_weight = pos_weight

def forward(self, input, target):
    epsilon = 10 ** -44
    my_bce_loss = -1 * (self.pos_weight * target * F.logsigmoid(input + epsilon)
                        + (1 - target) * log(1 - sigmoid(input) + epsilon))
    add_loss = (target - 0.5) ** 2 * 4
    mean_loss = (my_bce_loss * add_loss).mean()
    return mean_loss
```

`epsilon` was chosen so the log will be bounded to -100, as suggested in [BCE loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bceloss).

However I'm still getting NaN errors, **after several epochs**:

```
Function 'LogBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.
```

or

```
Function 'SigmoidBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.
```

Any suggestions how can I correct my loss function? maybe by somehow inherit and modify `forward` function?

---

**Update**:
The way I call my custom loss function:

```
y = batch[:, -1, :].to(self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
y_pred_batch = self.model(x)

LossFun = myLoss(self.pos_weight)
batch_result.loss = LossFun.forward(y_pred_batch, y)
```

I use [Temporal Convolutional Network model](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN/blob/master/TCN/tcn.py), implemented as follows:

```
out = self.conv1(x)
out = self.chomp1(out)               
out = self.elu(out) 
out = self.dropout1(out)
res = x if self.downsample is None else self.downsample(x)
return self.tanh(out + res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```py
class myLoss(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, pos_weight=1):
      super().__init__()
      self.pos_weight = pos_weight

    def forward(self, input, target):
      epsilon = 10 ** -44
      input = input.sigmoid().clamp(epsilon, 1 - epsilon)

      my_bce_loss = -1 * (self.pos_weight * target * torch.log(input)
                          + (1 - target) * torch.log(1 - input))
      add_loss = (target - 0.5) ** 2 * 4
      mean_loss = (my_bce_loss * add_loss).mean()
      return mean_loss
```

To test I perform 1000 backwards:

```py
target = torch.randint(high=2, size=(32,))
loss_fn = myLoss()
for i in range(1000):
  inp = torch.rand(1, 32, requires_grad=True)
  loss = loss_fn(inp, target)
  loss.backward()
  if torch.isnan(loss):
    print('Loss NaN')
  if torch.isnan(inp.grad).any():
    print('NaN')
```

All works nice.

Comment: I'm giving it a try!

Comment: Update:
File ".../training.py", line 511, in forward
    + (1 - target) * torch.log(1 - input))

Function 'LogBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.
Sadly, Error remains

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call your loss function?